# Why doesn't my @Cachable annotated method cache the result with EHCache?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, spring-annotations

I have an interceptor in Spring, which autowires two different services.
Both services have methods that are tagged with `@Cacheable` from the ehcache-spring-annotations project, but with different `cacheNames`.

```
public class MenuInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private EventService eventService;

    @Autowired
    private OrganisationInfoService orgService;

    @Override
    public final void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response,
                       Object handler,
                       ModelAndView modelAndView) throws SystemException {
        eventService.getFolderEventsForUser(123);
        orgService.getOrgCustomProfile("abc");

    }

@Service
public class EventServiceImpl implements EventService {
    @Override
    @Cacheable(cacheName = "ecomOrders")
    public Collection<FolderEventBean> getFolderEventsForUser(long loginId) throws SystemException {


@Service("organisationInfoService")
public class OrganisationInfoServiceImpl implements OrganisationInfoService {
    @Override
    @Cacheable(cacheName="orgProfile")
    public OrgCustomProfileBean getOrgCustomProfile(String orgHierarchyString) throws ServiceException {
```

When I run my application, one method successfully uses EHCache for the result, while the other does not. The `OrganisationInfoSericeImpl.getOrgCustomProfile()` caches properly, while the `EventServiceImpl.getFolderEvnetsForUser` does not. Can someone please tell me why?

I have tried to use same cache for both services, but still only one of them works.
I turned on DEBUG for ehcache-spring-annotations, and it registers both methods during startup:

> [DEBUG] 08:09:01 () Adding CACHE advised method 'getFolderEventsForUser' with attribute: CacheableAttributeImpl [cache=[ name = ecomOrders status = STATUS_ALIVE eternal = false overflowToDisk = false maxElementsInMemory = 100 maxElementsOnDisk = 0 memoryStoreEvictionPolicy = LRU timeToLiveSeconds = 300 timeToIdleSeconds = 0 diskPersistent = false diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds = 120 cacheEventListeners: net.sf.ehcache.statistics.LiveCacheStatisticsWrapper  hitCount = 0 memoryStoreHitCount = 0 diskStoreHitCount = 0 missCountNotFound = 0 missCountExpired = 0 ], cacheKeyGenerator=HashCodeCacheKeyGenerator [includeMethod=true, includeParameterTypes=true, useReflection=false, checkforCycles=false], entryFactory=null, exceptionCache=null, parameterMask=ParameterMask [mask=[]]] []  at com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl.getMethodAttribute(CacheAttributeSourceImpl.java:174)
>
> [DEBUG] 08:09:01 () Adding CACHE advised method 'getOrgCustomProfile' with attribute: CacheableAttributeImpl [cache=[ name = orgProfile status = STATUS_ALIVE eternal = false overflowToDisk = false maxElementsInMemory = 200 maxElementsOnDisk = 0 memoryStoreEvictionPolicy = LRU timeToLiveSeconds = 86400 timeToIdleSeconds = 0 diskPersistent = false diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds = 120 cacheEventListeners: net.sf.ehcache.statistics.LiveCacheStatisticsWrapper  hitCount = 0 memoryStoreHitCount = 0 diskStoreHitCount = 0 missCountNotFound = 0 missCountExpired = 0 ], cacheKeyGenerator=HashCodeCacheKeyGenerator [includeMethod=true, includeParameterTypes=true, useReflection=false, checkforCycles=false], entryFactory=null, exceptionCache=null, parameterMask=ParameterMask [mask=[]]] []  at com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl.getMethodAttribute(CacheAttributeSourceImpl.java:174)

When the interceptor calls the autowired services, only one of them caches:

> [DEBUG] 08:09:19 (UNIQUE_ID) Generated key '-1668638847278617' for invocation: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public abstract no.finntech.base.modules.organisation.support.OrgCustomProfileBean no.finntech.service.organisation.OrganisationInfoService.getOrgCustomProfile(java.lang.String) throws no.finntech.service.ServiceException; target is of class [no.finntech.service.organisation.impl.OrganisationInfoServiceImpl] [URI: /finn/minfinn/myitems/list, Remote IP: 127.0.0.1, Referer: , User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2]  at com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.interceptor.EhCacheInterceptor.generateCacheKey(EhCacheInterceptor.java:272)

EDIT:
I should probably mention that the two services are defined in different maven modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the reason was related to context:component-scan.
The service that failed to cache, was included in two different component scans. As soon as I resolved that the caching worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

How are you calling the second method, is it through the OrganisationInfoService interface?  The annotations rely on calling the method through an interface so a proxy can be generated that does the caching.

If you are calling the concrete class directly either externally or as a call from another method in the class the annotations won't work.

See answers 3 and 4 in the FAQ:
http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Comment: Both are called through their respective interfaces.

Comment: Hmm, the first cache has a timeToLive value of 300secs compared to the other one (which is 86400s) - this means cached objects will be evicted after 5mins regardless of last access time, so if the method is only called rarely for a given loginId it'll look like things aren't cached.  Might that be the reason?

Comment: At the moment I am just testing this out, and checking if it is cached at all. The calls are made within a few seconds of each other. The cache proxy is never used for the EventService, so there must be some sort of setup/configuration issue I guess.